# No return on command line when running Ruby script

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to test out some of the code I write from a book, and created a ruby script to do so.

Right now, I'm supposed to use either shift, push, pop, or unshift to reverse the order of a string.

To do this, I wrote ->

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
def reverse(string)
    reverse = []

    string.split.each do | char | 
        reverse.unshift(char)
    end

    reverse.join
end

reverse("Hello")
```

When I run the script in command line though, nothing returns ->

```
Stepans-MacBook-Pro-2:atlas stepan$ /Users/stepan/Desktop/ruby_tester.rb 
Stepans-MacBook-Pro-2:atlas stepan$
```

What's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to output the response. Try `puts reverse("Hello")`.