# Why Can't You See Return Value of a Ruby Script in Command Line?

Tags: ruby, shell, irb

My question is a follow up to this question: [No return on command line when running Ruby script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048907/no-return-on-command-line-when-running-ruby-script) because the answer doesn't offer an explanation:

Take the following file, `script.rb`:

```ruby
def hello(names)
  names.map {|name| "#{name} is awesome!"}
end

hello(["mark", "tony", "scott"])
```

When executing the file on the command line with `ruby script.rb` the return value of the following function does not appear. However, testing the method in IRB or by dropping into the code with PRY outputs an explicit return value. Why isn't the return value visible via script execution?

P.S. I am aware that using `puts` will output code into the terminal but I'm interested in why the **return** value doesn't output.

Comment: is there a language that _does_ display the last return value to the command line in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really simple: Bash (or whatever shell you are using) and Ruby are different programming languages. Bash doesn't know anything about Ruby. It doesn't know what a " Ruby return" is, it doesn't know what a "Ruby array" is, it doesn't know what a "Ruby string" is. Therefore, you simply *cannot possibly* return a Ruby object to Bash.

In fact, the shell usually just uses some operating system function to execute the Ruby script (e.g. the classical `fork` and `exec` or something like `vfork` or `clone`). If you wanted to return values this way, the operating system kernel would have to know about the semantics of every programming language ever invented plus every programming language that is going to be invented in the future. That is just not feasible.

Note that a command *can* return a value to the shell, namely an integer between 0 and 255 intended as a *status code* (with 0 meaning "success" and nonzero meaning "error"), and you can set that return value by calling `Kernel#exit`.

Answer (score 2):

Because both **IRB** or **Pry** are [REPL's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop)

*REPL* stands for: **read**, **evaluate**, **print** and **loop**. And that's exactly what both **Pry** and **IRB** are doing.

They will first read your input, evaluate your code, print the result of the code execution and then start over.

Answer (score 1):

A Ruby script can't return a value directly like you want it to, the Bash shell works in the same way, a Bash function can't return a string directly. You can return a string (with stdout) and assign it to the variable.

```
~:$~  cat scr.rb
~:$~  puts "Something here"
~:$~  echo $(ruby ./scr.rb) 
Something here
~:$~  myvar=$(echo $(ruby ./scr.rb))
~:$~  echo $myvar
Something here
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same question myself when I started coding. If you have a closer look at your code you can see why it doesn't print anything. You are actually no asking it in your code. Imagine having a huge script of thousands of lines and you want to execute it. You would have millions of pointless outputs if `ruby myscript.rb` worked the same way as the REPLs.

In addition, if you do want it to work that way, you can just do require the script inside the REPL session ( `require_relative 'your_script'` ) and then if you call your function `hello` it will work the way you describe.

Answer (score 0):

I can use the [`ruval`](https://rubygems.org/gems/ruval) gem. It evaluates each statement and returns its value.

```rb
$ ruval names.rb
def hello(names)
  names.map {|name| "#{name} is awesome!"}
end
=> hello
hello(["mark", "tony", "scott"])
=> ["mark is awesome!", "tony is awesome!", "scott is awesome!"]
```